# Multiple consumers but only one of each kind

Tags: spring-amqp

I have services A, B and C (and possibly more) and I may have N<sub>A</sub>, N<sub>B</sub> and N<sub>C</sub> running instances of each.

I want to be able to notify services A, B and C (and every other that may exist) that a given event has occurred (as in *fanout*), but I want that only exactly one instance of each service receives the notification (as in a *work queue*).

Can this be achieved with Spring AMQP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each your service must provide its own queue binded to that fanout exchange. Independently of instance (but not service) the queue must be the same. So, it will look like several consumer on the same queue, but only one of them will receive a message.

Frankly, you don't need to think about duplications at all. Just develop the app like it will be as only instance. And distribute it in cluster. Only one consumer (per service) will handle your message.